# Is it possible to let ABPersonViewController display only a multivalued property with a specific label?

Tags: ios, abaddressbook, abpersonviewcontroller

Assuming, I have an `ABAddressBook` with a person record that has a valid work address and an invalid home address.
I want to use an `ABPersonViewController` to let the user correct the invalid address. An `ABPersonViewController` has a property `displayedProperties` that allows to specify which properties are displayed. One can choose any `ABPropertyID`, among them `kABPersonAddressProperty`. If done so, the `ABPersonViewController` displays ALL addresses of the person record. Thus the user has no indication which one should be corrected.
I would like to specify that only an address with a specific label, say `@"home"` should be displayed. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible, as you've surmised. Beyond `displayedProperties`, the `ABPersonViewController` does not expose API for displaying only the `kABHomeLabel` property, say, of a multivalued property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, you are right! However I found kind of a solution: The method -(void)setHighlightedItemForProperty:(ABPropertyID)property withIdentifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier lets me at least highlight the address that should be corrected.

Comment: @ReinhardMänner That's clever. Thanks for introducing me to that method.